# Making nice Urls in Yii

Tags: .htaccess, url, yii

I red a lot of tuttorials, but all lead me to the same error - Error 500 - Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

I'm using xampp on Windows and cofigured httpd.conf like this

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

changed in yii main.php

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
                    'caseSensitive'=>false, 
        'rules'=>array(  
                            '' => 'site/index',     

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

and added .htaccess in root folder (the same level where protected folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tests/

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But no matter what I write in .htaccess, I get this error. When I commented all out, links from yii are generated ok (without index.php), but then I have 404 error, because of wrong server configuration.

**EDIT:**

And error.log last few records:

> [Wed Nov 27 11:32:31.100063 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:58620] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:32:31.372163 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:58621] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:32:34.674379 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:58622] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:32:36.587084 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:58623] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:32:54.899832 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:58624] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:54:14.056192 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:59297] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 11:54:14.687425 2013] [core:alert] [pid 9520:tid 1572] [client ::1:59298] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.459885 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.525911 2013] [core:warn] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH00098: pid file C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.588934 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.625947 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.625947 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 12:42:00
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.625947 2013] [core:notice] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\users\kristineg\xamps\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/apache'
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.627948 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11320:tid 308] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4472
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:27.998083 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4472:tid 336] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:28.143138 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4472:tid 336] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:28.186154 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4472:tid 336] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:38.827074 2013] [core:alert] [pid 4472:tid 1640] [client ::1:61797] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:39.614364 2013] [core:alert] [pid 4472:tid 1652] [client ::1:61796] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:39.958491 2013] [core:alert] [pid 4472:tid 1640] [client ::1:61798] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 15:53:40.295616 2013] [core:alert] [pid 4472:tid 1652] [client ::1:61799] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
>   [Wed Nov 27 16:32:32.894114 2013] [core:alert] [pid 4472:tid 1640] [client ::1:62407] C:/Users/kristineg/xamps/htdocs/xampp/tests/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have the `mode_rewrite` module loaded in your server's main config. For starters, modify your `.htaccess` so it looks like this:

```
IndexIgnore */*

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /tests/

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

If things change for the better (i.e. no 500-errors), see your main `httpd.conf` and look for a line that starts like this:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module ...
```

Uncomment that line by removing the leading `#` and restart the server process.

As for the "Options not allowed here" error, see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/86999).

Comment: Uncommented that line, restarted server and changed .htaccess, but the same error :(

Comment: There must be something else wrong then. Can you check the error log? Should be in `apache\logs\error.log`.

Comment: Just added last log records. Hmm, ".htaccess: Options not allowed here". It's located right in the root folder.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that. Looks like you need to pull that Options stanza into your main config.